# Assigning a value to an optional variable

Tags: swift, option-type

To set a dictionary value, I am doing like below.

```
var dic: [String:Any]?

dic = [String:Any]()

dic!["name"] = "my name"
dic!["email"] = "aaa@bbb.com"
dic!["nickname"] = "Grrrrrrrr"
```

I think the exclamation mark (!) is superfluous. 
That is, I'd like to set without '!'.

```
dic = [String:Any]()

dic["name"] = "my name"
dic["email"] = "aaa@bbb.com"
dic["nickname"] = "Grrrrrrrr"
```

Is there any way to use in short to set a value to optional variable?

Comment: Why is `dic` an optional? Just declare and initialize in one step: `var dic = [String: Any]()`.

Comment: The dic is a JSON object that is retrieved from REST API. so it could be empty.

Comment: What I showed you is an empty dictionary.

Comment: I mean the JSON object is not what I feed, but what Alamofire feeds. Alamofire's return value is optional. my code is supposing that case.

Comment: It would be much better if you updated your question with real code showing what you are really trying to fix.

Comment: Why don't you just keep it optional like `dic?["name"] = "my name"`, `dic?["email"] = "aaa@bbb.com"`?

Comment: @Kamran, I want to decrease the usage of question mark '?', and not beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having read the comments, the solution below could be what you are looking for.

```
var dic = [String: Any]() //Empty dictionary

func processResultOfAlamofire(_ result: [String: Any]?) {
    dic = result ?? [String: Any]()
}
```

If the result of Alamo is `nil`, `dic`will be empty instead of `nil`. The `??` operator could be written as:

```
if result == nil {
    dic = [String: Any]()
} else {
    dic = result!
}
```

Comment: Or even more concise: `dic = result ?? [:]` as the type is already known

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should update your code, Don't use direct dictionary in your viewcontroller. set optional variable in your model. and when ever you use those values use it with conditional checking like, if let value = somethingOptional{}

or use guard in your API call function so it will never update or effect any view if you are getting values null from API